# Javascript regex - split string

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

Struggling with a regex requirement. I need to split a string into an array wherever it finds a forward slash. But not if the forward slash is preceded by an escape.

Eg, if I have this string:

```
hello/world
```

I would like it to be split into an array like so:

```
arrayName[0] = hello
arrayName[1] = world
```

And if I have this string:

```
hello/wo\/rld
```

I would like it to be split into an array like so:

```
arrayName[0] = hello
arrayName[1] = wo/rld
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This page will probably help: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript  Not posting this as an *answer* because I don't have time right now to come up with an example specific to what you need. But I'm quite certain you can get there from that post. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is a little long-winded but will work, and avoids the problem with [IE's broken split implementation](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/cross-browser-split) by not using a regular expression.

```
function splitPath(str) {
    var rawParts = str.split("/"), parts = [];
    for (var i = 0, len = rawParts.length, part; i < len; ++i) {
        part = "";
        while (rawParts[i].slice(-1) == "\\") {
            part += rawParts[i++].slice(0, -1) + "/";
        }
        parts.push(part + rawParts[i]);
    }
    return parts;
}

var str = "hello/world\\/foo/bar";
alert( splitPath(str).join(",") );
```

Comment: Cheers! This seems like the solution I've been looking for.

Answer (score 23):

I wouldn't use `split()` for this job.  It's much easier to match the path components themselves, rather than the delimiters. For example:

```
var subject = 'hello/wo\\/rld';
var regex = /(?:[^\/\\]+|\\.)+/g;
var matched = null;
while (matched = regex.exec(subject)) {
  print(matched[0]);
}
```

output:

```
hello
wo\/rld
```

**[test it at ideone.com](http://ideone.com/2Geah)**

Comment: This looks the best answer to me.

Comment: Agreed.  Definitely the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way adapted from the techniques in [this blog post](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript):

```
var str = "Testing/one\\/two\\/three";
var result = str.replace(/(\\)?\//g, function($0, $1){
  return $1 ? '/' : '[****]';
}).split('[****]');
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/aroli5)

Given:

```
Testing/one\/two\/three
```

The result is:

```
[0]: Testing
[1]: one/two/three
```

That first uses the simple "fake" lookbehind to replace `/` with `[****]` and to replace `\/` with `/`, then splits on the `[****]` value. (Obviously, replace `[****]` with anything that won't be in the string.)

Comment: Thanks :) This is the kind of thing that would be suitable for me.

Answer (score 1):

/*
If you are getting your string from an ajax response or a data base query,
that is, the string has not been interpreted by javascript,
you can match character sequences that either have no slash or have escaped slashes.
If you are defining the string in a script, escape the escapes and strip them after the match.
*/

```
var s='hello/wor\\/ld';
s=s.match(/(([^\/]*(\\\/)+)([^\/]*)+|([^\/]+))/g) || [s];
alert(s.join('\n'))
s.join('\n').replace(/\\/g,'')

/*  returned value: (String)
hello
wor/ld
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example at [rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/r/9ryLMWAGEA)

Comment: Which may be great for Ruby, but doesn't look like it works for JavaScript, at least not with `split`: http://jsbin.com/ipote5 If you were thinking of using it another way, I'd recommend posting that.

Comment: Please post the solution here instead of on another site.

Comment: This doesn't work: `"hello/wor\/rld".match(/([a-z]+(\\\/)?[a-z]+)/)` => `["hello", "hello", undefined]`

Comment: @Justin: It does work if you use the `g` identifier `str.match(/[a-z]+(\\\/)?[a-z]+/g);`, but it fails if there's more than one `\/`. (Or any other characters beside lowercase letters for that matter)

Comment: Hence the importance of posting the solution here as you said.

Comment: oh ffs, just replace \/ with @@@, split by / and undo the replacement

Answer (score 0):

For short code, you can use reverse to simulate negative lookbehind

```
function reverse(s){
  return s.split('').reverse().join('');
}

var parts = reverse(myString).split(/[/](?!\\(?:\\\\)*(?:[^\\]|$))/g).reverse();
for (var i = parts.length; --i >= 0;) { parts[i] = reverse(parts[i]); }
```

but to be efficient, it's probably better to split on `/[/]/` and then walk the array and rejoin elements that have an escape at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may take care of it for you.

```
var str = "/hello/wo\\/rld/";
var split = str.replace(/^\/|\\?\/|\/$/g, function(match) {
  if (match.indexOf('\\') == -1) {
    return '\x00';
  }
  return match;
}).split('\x00');       

alert(split);
```