# how to split a string in js with some exceptions

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

I have this string:

```
a\,bcde,fgh,ijk\,lmno,pqrst\,uv
```

I need a JavaScript function that will split the string by every `,` but only those that **don't** have a `\` before them

How can this be done?

Comment: Duplicate question?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/820172/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-string-while-ignoring-escaped-commas

Comment: @Eran that question is about Java. Unfortunately Javascript does not know lookbehinds, so that solution is not working here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript regex - split string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853118/javascript-regex-split-string)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's the shortest thing I could come up with:

```
'a\\,bcde,fgh,ijk\\,lmno,pqrst\\,uv'.replace(/([^\\]),/g, '$1\u000B').split('\u000B')
```

The idea behind is to find every place where comma isn't prefixed with a backslash, replace those with string that is uncommon to come up in your strings and then split by that *uncommon* string.

Note that **backslashes** before commas **have to be escaped** using another backslash. Otherwise, javascript treats form `\,` as escaped comma and produce simply a comma out of it! In other words if you won't escape the backslash, javascript sees this: `a\,bcde,fgh,ijk\,lmno,pqrst\,uv` as this `a,bcde,fgh,ijk,lmno,pqrst,uv`.

Comment: Thanks, why are you using a `~`?

Comment: You can use anything instead of `~`. It have to be something (even something longer than `~`) that you are sure won't come up in a string that is being split up, because in the next step (after replace) we're splitting the string using that character(s).

Comment: I recommend using any non-printable character instead of ~. E.g. it can be \u000B which corresponds to code of zero-width space.

Comment: What didn't do anything? :) Please note, that backslashes before colons **has to be escaped** using another backslash. Otherwise, javascript treats form `\,` as escaped colon and produce simply colon out of it! In other words if you won't escape the backslash, javascript sees this: `a\,bcde,fgh,ijk\,lmno,pqrst\,uv` as this `a,bcde,fgh,ijk,lmno,pqrst,uv`.

Answer (score 4):

Since regular expressions in JavaScript does not support [lookbehinds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind), I'm not going to cook up a giant hack to mimic this behavior. Instead, you can just `split()` on all commas (`,`) and then glue back the pieces that shouldn't have been split in the first place.

Quick 'n' dirty [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/THdhf/1/):

```
var str = 'a\\,bcde,fgh,ijk\\,lmno,pqrst\\,uv'.split(','), // Split on all commas
    out = []; // Output

for (var i = 0, j = str.length - 1; i < j; i++) { // Iterate all but last (last can never be glued to non-existing next)
    var curr = str[i]; // This piece
    if (curr.charAt(curr.length - 1) == '\\') { // If ends with \ ...
        curr += ',' + str[++i]; // ... glue with next and skip next (increment i)
    }
    out.push(curr); // Add to output
}
```

Comment: I think this solution look like a very big workaround while there is solution presented by WTK

Comment: @Eskat0n Indeed it *is* a workaround ... a workaround that happens to span more lines than other answers :)

Comment: This solution fails if you have multiple escaped ',' before a non escaped ','. E.G. `"ab\\,c\\,ed,fg"`.

Change:
    `for (var i = 0, j = str.length - 1; i < j; i++) {`
to:
    `while (var i = 0, j = str.length - 1; i < j; i++) {`
to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2):

In 2022 most of browsers support lookbehinds:
https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind

Safari should be your only concern.

With a lookbehind you can split your string this way:

```
"a\\,bcde,fgh,ijk\\,lmno,pqrst\\,uv".split(/(?<!\\),/)
// => ['a\\,bcde', 'fgh', 'ijk\\,lmno', 'pqrst\\,uv']
```

Answer (score 1):

Another ugly hack around the lack of look-behinds:

```
function rev(s) {
    return s.split('').reverse().join('');
}

var s = 'a\\,bcde,fgh,ijk\\,lmno,pqrst\\,uv';

// Enter bizarro world...
var r = rev(s);

// Split with a look-ahead
var rparts = r.split(/,(?!\\)/);

// And put it back together with double reversing.
var sparts = [ ];
while(rparts.length)
    sparts.push(rev(rparts.pop()));

for(var i = 0; i < sparts.length; ++i)
    $('#out').append('<pre>' + sparts[i] + '</pre>');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/QbBfw/1/

I don't think I'd do this in real life but it works even if it does make me feel dirty. Consider this a curiosity rather than something you should really use.

Answer (score 1):

In case if need remove backslashes also:

```
var test='a\\.b.c';
var result = test.replace(/\\?\./g, function (t) { return t == '.' ? '\u000B' : '.'; }).split('\u000B');
//result: ["a.b", "c"]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use regex to do the split.

Here is the link to regex in javascript http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Here is the link to other post where the author have used regex for split [Javascript won't split using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812144/javascript-wont-split-using-regex)

From the first link if you note you can create a regular expression using

?!n Matches any string that is not followed by a specific string n

```
[,]!\\
```

Comment: Of course you can use a regex to split the string. Question is HOW to split the string in a way author asked for.

Comment: Yeah, this is not what the author wants. I'm thinking to loop with .each every split with commas, and check wheter the previous each part has or not a "/" at the end... If it has, concat both

Comment: @WTK The first link covered the answer, just didn't wanted spoonfeeding. Have edited the answer again to include more information based on your suggestions though

Comment: @ GoRoS, can you please write the exact function for you idea?

Comment: Yeah, I'd like to see that too. Note that link provided in the first comment was refering to Java which has different implementation of regular expression.