# Regex to split on period

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to split a string on period. E.g. of such a string would be ...

```
1) a.b.c
2) a\.x.b.c
```

Result for 1) should be ... `["a", "b", "c"]`
Result for 2) should be ... `["a.x", "b", "c"]`

Thanks
Prashant

Comment: Why is the first period ignored in scenario 2?

Comment: Result for 2) is wrong, if it were split on period, then it should be ["a","x","b","c"].
Also, [.] should do the trick.

Comment: ignored because of the escape "\"

Comment: The edit changes things somewhat ;)

Comment: does your interpreted string look like (a) "a\\.x.b.c", or like (b) "a\.x.b.c"? If you alert/log (a) you get a\.x.b.c, if you alert/log (b) you get a.x.b.c ... If your case is like (b), your backslash is interpreted as an escape, like you said and I don't believe you can do an operation _on_ that backslash in this case

Comment: I dont show the string anywhere. It is purely for processing purposes. The string looks like this "a\.x.b.c"

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to split a string in js with some exceptions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329972/how-to-split-a-string-in-js-with-some-exceptions)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too familiar with JavaScript, but maybe this is enough to get you started in the right direction.

```
var s='a\\.x.b.c';
s.match(/(([^\\.]|\\.)+)/g, function($1) { print($1); });
```

Result:

```
a\.x,b,c
```

You are not clear on how backslash should work, so I am assuming you are using a backslash as a general escape mechanism; that means `\\.` means a literal backslash (escaped with an escape backslash) followed by a literal, that is, unescaped dot.  If that's not what you mean, you need to define this in more detail (or, more likely, have an epiphany that you are Doing It Wrong somehow).

Comment: You are right. I learnt that it will have to be "a\\.x.b.c" and not "a\.x.b.c". I will try your solution later. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because there's no lookbehind on Javascript regex, I recommend you to have a look at [this](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript), where they mimic the behaviour of the lookbehind.

Comment: Forgot to mention that this needs to be in Javascript

Comment: @user1031396 that changes everything as Javascript doesn't support lookbehind. Let me see if I can find a workaround..